# Chrome & firefox downloads fail but edge is fine Windows 10

Tags: networking, google-chrome, firefox

I have a windows 10 work PC that operates totally fine on the corporate network. I took it home to work more over the holidays. Now, file downloads fail using both Chrome and Firefox, but not Edge. Websites load fine in all three browsers.

It is common to all file downloads. It doesn't matter what the external site is.

The machine is plugged into my router with a wired connection.

Other computers on the same home network can download files fine.

The work PC does not have any special networking config (indeed I set it up). The corporate network functions exactly like a home network.

Of course I tried rebooting the machine.

Interestingly, when I tried to run

```
ipconfig /renew all
```

I get the message

```
The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation
```

Pings to external sites work fine, so DNS and connectivity seem fine.

Does anyone have ideas for what I can check?

EDIT:

When firefox fails, it gives the message:

```
C:\Users\<myUserName>\AppData\Local\Temp\oHWXPrWp.exe.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read
```

Could this be a file writing issue?

Also, when I try to update intelliJ though its internal updater process, it gives this error

```
Failed to prepare an update: Cannot download 'https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/IC-183.4588.61-183.4886.37-patch-win.jar': Connection reset , response: 200 OK
```

I tried reinstalling chrome - same issue.

I tried reinstalling firefox, but when I try to run the downloader, it says file is corrupt. :-(

Answer (score 2):

#### The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for this operation

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Comment: I did everything as you suggested, and it still fails in the same way.